# Is there a way to create an object by using a variable that stores the type?

Tags: c#, instantiation

here is what im trying to do,

```
someClass object = new someClass();
Type a=object.GetType();
a someOtherObject =new a();
```

but the variable a can't be used in place of someClass even though i saved it as a type. I was wondering if there is an alternative method of doing something like this.

As for the why, i want to make a method that takes in a list of monster in my game and it picks a random one, creates a new object out of the one it has chosen and adds it to a seperate list.

Comment: You could use Activator.CreateInstance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Activator.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8) for the purpose

```
var obj = new someClass();
Type type = obj.GetType();
var someOtherObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: whats the difference between using var and someClass?

Comment: var is an implicitly typed local variable, which is equivalent to a strongly typed variable, the only difference is that the compiler automatically determines the type. So with regard to context of your question, using both var and someClass is equivalent. The Compiler recognizes that obj is of type someClass

Comment: You could read more on var here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var